# You cannot use the "markdown_to_html" filter as no Markdown library is available

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, markdown

I am using Symfony 5.3.9 with PHP 7.4.24 and Composer 2.1.8. I want to render the following template with **markdown_to_html** but I am getting an error.

This is blog.html.twig

```
...
<article class="text-center">
    {{ content | markdown_to_html }}
</article>
...
```

And this is the error that I am getting:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("You cannot use the "**markdown_to_html**" filter as no Markdown library is available; try running "composer require league/**html-to-markdown**".").

I run `composer require league/html-to-markdown` but it says "Nothing to install, update or remove".

My composer.json:

```json
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.4.24",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "^1.10",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.1",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.7",
        "league/html-to-markdown": "^5.0",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.2",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.5",
        "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/asset": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/console": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/form": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/intl": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/mime": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/notifier": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/process": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/string": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/translation": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/validator": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "5.3.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "5.3.*",
        "twig/cssinliner-extra": "^3.3",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^3.3",
        "twig/inky-extra": "^3.3",
        "twig/markdown-extra": "^3.3",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/browser-kit": "^5.3",
        "symfony/css-selector": "^5.3",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "^5.3",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.20",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^5.3",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "^5.3",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "^5.3",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "^5.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "5.3.*"
        }
    }
}
```

I have followed this documentation https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/markdown_to_html.html . What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're trying to use `markdown_to_html` by installing a package named `html-to-markdown`? Wouldn't that package allow you to do the opposite from what you want?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, no. The error message says "try running "composer require league/html-to-markdown"

Comment: I have installed the required dependencies https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/markdown_to_html.html but I have error message that says: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("You cannot use the "markdown_to_html" filter as no Markdown library is available; try running "composer require league/html-to-markdown".").

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, when I run `composer require twig/markdown-extra` it says "Nothing to install, update or remove"

Comment: That makes no sense since league/html-to-markdown is for converting HTML code into markdown, while the function `markdown_to_html` would convert markdown into HTML. Or is the function name just wrong?

Comment: When I run `composer require twig/extra-bundle` it says "Nothing to install, update or remove".

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, according to the documentation the function is named `markdown_to_html`. https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/markdown_to_html.html

Comment: I know about twigs function, but I don't see the relevance between that function and the package `html-to-markdown` which is for doing the opposite from what that function should do.

Comment: @ihan composer require league/commonmark should get your going.  The error message is just plain wrong.  twig/markdown-extra uses external libraries to do the actual rendering.  You can see a note about this all the way down at the bottom of the link you posted.

Comment: "Afterwards you need to install a markdown library of your choice" - which one did you choose? `league/html-to-markdown` lets me think that this is a converter from HTML to Markdown, most probably that cannot resolve the filter `markdown_to_html`. Recommending this is a bug in the package `twigphp/markdown-extra` which got fixed some days ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to execute:

```
composer require league/commonmark
```

The twig/markdown-extra package just provides a twig extension for calling the markdown processor.  You still need to install an actual markdown package.  This is sort of documented at the very end of the markdown_to_html page but it is not very clear.

If no markdown packages are found then the html_to_markdown suggestion is emitted.  Which would be fine if that is what was needed but markdown_to_html is a far more common requirement.  Hence all the comments.  The suggestion will be fixed in the next release.

And just for info, the league package is not the only one supported.  You could also use:

```
   "require-dev": {
        "erusev/parsedown": "^1.7",
        "league/commonmark": "^1.0",
        "league/html-to-markdown": "^4.8|^5.0",
        "michelf/php-markdown": "^1.8"
```

As listed in markdown-extra/composer.json